# Prevent coder's error "forget to divide by time" in Physics simulation

Tags: c++, c++11

In Physics logic, I am accustomed to code like this :-

```
Position+=Velocity;
Velocity+=Acceleration;

//unit of Velocity = unit of Position / time-step      
//unit of Acceleration = unit of Position / (time-step^2)
```

They are all **Vector3D** - my custom class. 
The code works OK.

Then, I revolutionized my library to match standard of popular physic engines, e.g. Bullet.
The time unit is now **second** (or minutes, etc), not **time-step** anymore.

Now the valid code becomes:

```
Position+=Velocity*time_per_timestep;
Velocity+=Acceleration*time_per_timestep;
```

When the statement is a little complex, it is not easy to realize that the following code that I just added is wrong:

```
Vector3D velocity=rigidBody->getPosition()-calibrator->getLastPosition();
```

In some busy/dizzy days, I forgot to add `÷ time_per_timestep` like that.
As a result, my bad day began.

### **Question:**

How to prevent this human error? (with assert?)

### **My poor solution:**

I would create classes `Position`, `Velocity`, and `Acceleration` to enforce it.
 For example, `Position minus Position` will still return `Position`. I have to enforce that `Position` cannot implicitly casted to be `Velocity`.
**Disadvantages:** Too tedious, reduce maintainability(?), and overkill(?).

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_units.html

Comment: It's indeed a pretty good solution. [boost::posix_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) uses a similar approach.

Comment: [This may be of interest to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381918/preferred-mechanism-to-attach-a-type-to-a-scalar)

Comment: `Position+=Velocity; Velocity+=Acceleration;` isn't logical based on physics

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc  Yes, you are correct, but old bad habits die hard.

Comment: Write unit tests.

Comment: @Pete Becker For every function?  In unit test, I would forget to divide it again.  Thus, my wrong unit test will report that my wrong program is correct.  Did I miss something?

Comment: If your unit tests don't detect that the result is wrong your tests are, indeed, wrong. But that's because they`re not testing the right thing.

Comment: @Pete Becker  I think Unit test can not solve this issue.  For example, how can I create the unit test if the function is : `Vector3 getVelocity(){ return rigidBody->getPosition()-calibrator->getLastPosition();  }` ?    Should the unit test be  `bool shouldBeTrue= getVelocity(a,b) ==  a->getPosition()-b->getLastPosition();`?     If I am careful enough to create a correct unit test, there is high probability that the function is correct in the first place.

Comment: Correct unit tests, give you assurance that you haven't broken anything when you change the code. Unit tests that simply duplicate what a function does are, as you say, not effective. Unit tests should check that the code being tests **meets its specification**. For a physics system, you might, for example, test the position of a particle that's moving at a particular velocity, before and after a given time interval. You know how far it should have moved, and if the system isn't calculating that correctly (regardless of the internal details of the function) you know that you've made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a unit tags type:

```
template<std::ptrdiff_t...Units>
struct unit_tags_t {
  template<std::ptrdiff_t...Lhs, std::ptrdiff_t...Rhs>
  friend unit_tags_t<(Lhs+Rhs)...>
  operator*( unit_tags_t<Lhs...>, unit_tags_t<Rhs...> ) {
    return {};
  }
  template<std::ptrdiff_t...Lhs, std::ptrdiff_t...Rhs>
  friend unit_tags_t<(Lhs-Rhs)...>
  operator/( unit_tags_t<Lhs...>, unit_tags_t<Rhs...> ) {
    return {};
  }
  friend unit_tags_t operator+( unit_tags_t, unit_tags_t ) { return {}; }
  friend unit_tags_t operator-( unit_tags_t, unit_tags_t ) { return {}; }
  friend unit_tags_t& operator+=( unit_tags_t& lhs, unit_tags_t ) { return lhs; }
  friend unit_tags_t& operator-=( unit_tags_t& lhs, unit_tags_t ) { return lhs; }
  friend unit_tags_t operator*( unit_tags_t ) { return {}; }
  friend unit_tags_t operator-( unit_tags_t ) { return {}; }
};
```

it is a compile-time list of signed values.

We pick some base units, like time and distance.

```
using base_time_t = unit_tags_t<1,0>;
using base_distance_t = unit_tags_t<0,1>;
```

Now, `base_time_t{}+base_distance_t{}` is a compile-time error, but `base_time_t{}+base_time_t{}` is not.

Similarly, `base_time_t{}*base_time_t{}` is not a compile-time error, but rather a new unit of "time squared".

Next, we define a tuple with augmented operators.  It has a scalar as one field, and some unit tag as its second field.  All arithmetic operations perform on each of the units in turn, like a mathematical product type.

So if we have

```
{2.0, base_distance_t}/{3.14, base_time_t}
```

we get

```
{0.636..., unit_tags_t<-1,1>{}}
```

by simply forwarding each operator to each component part.

Call this augmented tuple a "unit value".

The next step is to deal with scalars.  Define a global constant of

```
using time = unit_value<double, base_time_t>;
using distance = unit_value<double, base_distance_t>;
const time second(1./time_per_timestep, {});
const distance meter(1., {});
```

or whatever is right.  We can derive new types:

```
const auto meter_per_second = meter/second;
const auto meter_per_second_squared = meter/second/second;
using speed = std::decay_t<decltype(meter_per_second)>;
using acceleration = std::decay_t<decltype(meter_per_second_squared)>;
```

based off these.

Now, `getPosition` returns a `distance` value.

`velocity` is a value of type `speed`

And

```
Velocity3D velocity=rigidBody->getPosition()-calibrator->getLastPosition();
```

is a type error.

If you are using a compressed tuple, the space required for a `double` or a `unit_value<double, blah>` should be the same (as should the layout in memory).  So you could make `Velocity3D` to be a `unit_value<Vector3d, base_distance_t>`, or a `Vector3d< base_distance_t >`.

A library like boost units will do all this for you; I am simply illustrating how you'd approach it.

Comment: It looks very promising and make sense.   However, I can't make it compile. (https://ideone.com/kCzy1x)   Can you make it compile  OR show a full compilable code, please?

Comment: @java delete `using namespace std`, that is a bad idea at anything except aome function scope.  Define `time_per_timestep`.  I mean, the first error is "time_per_timestep is not defined"...  Have your `template class<A,B>` (whatever you call it) actually be a tuple-like and forward operators element-wise?

Comment: `class<A,B>` is what I just try to define what is `unit_value`, because your solution seems to omit that part.  Ok, now I define it, but got a new error.  Agree that `using namespace std` is a bad idea, this is just a fast test.  :)

Comment: @java it is an empty class; I do not get why you think it would do anything.  Provide your attempt at it, not nothing.  And fix your pile of unrelated syntax errors.  Like I said, if you want a prewritten one, boost has one.

Comment: Ha ha, I got it!  Now, I understand your cute tuple.    .... By the way, what do you think about User-defined literals?  I don't think it directly solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 offers you a correct solution to this problem with [User-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal).
This helps you to prevent incorrect operations between measures by checking them in compile time.

Comment: Thank.   It would be far better if you also provide an example code related to the OP's.  It doesn't need to be runable.

Comment: do you see the OP using any literals here?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, well obviously not. Hence the (incomplete) suggestion to do use them. You should also note that such derisive tone has no place here on SO.