# how can I create a type which behaves just like another type?

Tags: c++, templates, types

This question is motivated by [preferred mechanism to attach a type to a scalar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381918/preferred-mechanism-to-attach-a-type-to-a-scalar), but that got a bit off-track with units-of-measure ...

Let's say I want to create a `Float` which pretty much works just like `float` (this isn't necessarily radical, in C# `System.Float` is almost *exactly* the same as `float`; the only difference is that one is a type-name and the other is a keyword).

You might start out real simple with `struct Float final { float v; };`.  And then maybe adding a bunch of `operator` overloads

```
inline auto operator+(Float lhs, Float rhs) {
    return Float { lhs.v + rhs.v };
}
// ... and so on ...
inline bool operator<(Float lhs, Float rhs) {
    return lhs.v < rhs.v;
}
// ... etc. ...
```

Now, I need to be able to convert a `Float` to a `Double`

```
struct Double final { double v; };  
struct Float final { float v;
    operator Double() const { return Double { v }; }
};
```

Now maybe I add `operator&()` so that I can more easily interact with legacy code

```
extern void foo(const float*);
const Float f { 3.14 };
foo(&f);
```

instead of writing `foo(&f.v)`.

And the list goes on ... Then, I realize this code is the same for `Float` and `Double`, so I use templates:

```
template<typename T>
struct Type final { T v; }
using Float = Type<float>;
using Double = Type<double>;
```

But now I realize that `T` may not be cheap to copy like `float`, so I have to change my overloads

```
template<typename T>
inline auto make_Type(T&& v) {
    return Type<T> { std::forward<T>(v); }
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
inline auto operator+(const Type<T1>& lhs, const Type<T2>& rhs) {
   return make_Type(lhs.v + rhs.v);
}
```

And there are more complications for an arbitrary `T`; for example, it might be moveable, but not copyable.

Is there a "canonical" way to do something like this?  Or does it really start to get (very) messy?  Does it help to restrict `T` in some way? (I really only need `double`, `int`, etc., not `std::string` or `std::vector<T>`). Maybe somebody has already made it work well for (just about?) everything?

Remember that eventually I **really** want

```
template<typename T, typename Tag>
struct TaggedType final
{
typedef Tag tag_type;
typedef T value_type;
value_type value;
};
```

but not dealing with `Tag` seems to be a good simplification (and avoids the rabbit-hole of units).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A library that you are looking for was recently featured on "Standard C++" site.

See [Tutorial: Emulating strong/opaque typedefs in C++](https://foonathan.github.io/blog/2016/10/19/strong-typedefs.html)